# React-Native SQLite Data retrieval

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data back from sqlite in my react-native android app, but all I'm getting is [object object]

I'm getting the records count using the rows.length, but not the data. How can I display the data on to the console?
I have attached a screenshot also. 
Please help...

[image]

Comment: Source code could help us

Comment: '_queryRecordCount = () => {
        this.db.query("SELECT * from article", function (results) {
            console.log(results);
            alert("Total records count is " + results.rows.length);
        }, function (e) {
            console.log("### Error Message:" + e.message);
        });
    };'

Comment: I'm getting the output as [object object] when I try to display the results  using 'console.log(results)      @MOHAMMED SHEIK DAWOOD S

Comment: @Aiswarya is my answer not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
_queryRecordCount = () => {
    this.db.query("SELECT * from article", function(results) {
        let readable = JSON.stringify(results);
        alert(readable);
        alert("Total records count is " + results.rows.length);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("### Error Message:" + e.message);
    });
};
```

This should take the object data and turn it into a readable format for you.

You can also just loop through your data, and log the output.

Comment: I'm getting :  {"rows":{"length":2},"rowsAffected":0} @23K

Comment: So you're no longer seeing [object]?

Comment: Yes...But I want to see the data which I have entered.

Comment: _insertNewData = () => {
this.db.query("insert into article(title, content) values('Aiswarya','1234')", function (results) {
console.log(results);
alert("###Insert new record " + results.insertId + " successfully !");
}, function (e) {
console.log("### Error Message:" + e.message);
});
};


This is my code for saving two data’s on the database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I should have formatted myy question in a better way.

Comment: @Aiswarya Same issue facing, I can't get the data but only length is shown. Did you have the fix?

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this,

**To know total records:**

var len = results.rows.length;

console.log('total records ::::::' + len);

**Now for data printing:**

```
if (len > 0) 
{
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        let row = results.rows.item(i);
        console.log("row : "+ JSON.stringify(row));
    }
}
```

Sample code :

```
_queryRecordCount = () => {
    this.db.query("SELECT * from article", function (results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log('total records ::::::' + len);

        if (len > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let row = results.rows.item(i);
                console.log("row : "+ JSON.stringify(row));
            }
        }else{
            console.log("no records found");
        }
    }, function (e) {
        console.log("### Error Message:" + e.message);
    });
};
```